# Splitting MongoDB collections in multiple servers via mongos Router

Tags: mongodb, cloud, mongoid, mongomapper, nosql

Having a MongoDB database named `maindatabase` which has 3 document collections named users, tags and categories, I would like to know if it is possible having them splitted on three different servers separately (on different cloud service providers).

I mean not as a replica, but just one collection for server (one db with just categories collection on a server, one with users on another server and one for tags on the third server) may be routed by a mongos Router selectively.

Anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: It would be possible with mongoid 3.0. Take a look at https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-branch-master, search for `store_in`

Comment: Did you mean the following mongoid/CHANGELOG.md ? #1291 Mongoid now supports any number of database connections as defined in the mongoid.yml. For example you could have a local single server db, a multi availablity zone replica set, and a shard cluster all in the same application environment. Mongoid can connect to any session at any point in time.

Comment: @LucaGSoave yes, I was referring to that only.

Comment: Just curious: Why the need to separate collections into different cloud provider data centers? I can understand positioning replicaset nodes this way and having a DR strategy, but I'd love to hear the value proposition for geographically-separate collection stores.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, having a zero budget project and using free MongoID cloud services as MongoHQ + MongoLab + OtherMongos ... (everybody has a free Plan, nowadays), you can extend Data Crunching experimentation over the size limit of a single provider. If you have not budget problems just forget it :-)        ...unless you're like me and you just want to PLAY with the architectural limits of this awesome technology: http://bit.ly/JmzZon

Comment: You're asking for something that's simply not provided, so you can combine free accounts? If you're just trying to learn mongodb and use it free, why not just install it locally? It's very simple to set up, when you don't worry about replication, shards, and backup strategy (and you don't need any of that when just learning). Those free accounts are shared-system accounts, and you might actually get better performance on a local box (with more storage too - the free accounts are capped: MongoLab at 240MB; not sure of the others).

Comment: Yes thanks, I already have MongoDB on my laptop and a "MongoDB production site ( http://gitwatcher.com )" splitted on many clouds (all free plans) ... By the way, are you sure is not provided ? I still didn't try but I think YOU CAN (I'll have a try as soon as possible ).  Have a look at what Durran Jordan (the MongoID founder) say about that: http://bit.ly/LbFIOA

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @matulef's answer regarding manual manipulation of databases through `movePrimary`, maybe this calls for a simpler solution of just maintaining 3 database connections: one per server, each in a different cloud provider's data center as you originally specified. You wouldn't have the simplicity of a single `mongos` connection point, but with your three connections, you could then directly manipulate `users`, `tags`, and `categories` on each of their respective connections.

Comment: thanks for contributing David, I still won't close this Q. until some other views come about ... I also have to try something, thanks again until now.

Comment: This is the way I would go too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't currently split up the collections in a single database this way.  However it is possible to do this if you put each collection in a different database.  In a sharded system, each database has a "primary shard" associated with it, where all the unsharded collections on that database live.  If you separate your 3 collections into 3 different databases, you can individually move them to different shards using the "movePrimary" command:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/movePrimary+Command

There is, however, some overhead associated with making more databases, so it's not clear whether this is the best solution for your needs.

Comment: And movePrimary is dangerous.  Having done that you will find that some mongoses see the old primary location while some see the new.  See http://jira.mongodb.org for the long-standing issues in this command.